# Methods that copies the value of the instance variable to reverse digits & swap digits of a number in C#

Tags: c#

I m stuck with the my C# program, just can't figure out how to make it work.
Firstly I am supposed to create an instance variable for a 4digit Number and create getter & setter methods for that instance variable (Done with that).

Secondly I am supposed to create 4 methods:

1. method for summing up the digits.
2. method for copying the value of the instance variable & reversing the number.
3. method for copying the value of the instance variable & swapping first & last digits and 4th or swapping second & third digits.

Lastly there should be a Main method Main method that creates an object, assigns a four-digit number to the instance variable, and tests all methods.
Now I have come up with the following code but all the methods return me 0 except the SumDigits one which is working fine.
I will be grateful if some one can just help out in fixing this code.

```
    public class myClass
    {

    public int number=0;//instance variable
    public int r;
    public int sum = 0;
    public int rem ;
    public int reverse = 0;
    public string firstlast;
    public string secondthird;

    public myClass()//Constructor
    {
    }
        // set & get property
        public int MyNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return number;
            }
            set
            {
                number=value;
            }
        }

        //Setter and getter methods
    public void SetNumber(int fourNumber)
     {
        number = fourNumber;
     }
    public int GetNumber()
   {
       return number;
   }
```

//method to calculate and return the sum of the digits of the instance variable

```
        public int SumDigits()
   {

           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
                   r = number % 10;
                   number = number / 10;
                   sum = sum + r;
           }

       return sum;
   }
```

//method that copies the value of the instance variable, and then returns the value of the copy in a reverse order

```
        public int RevNum()
    {

        while (number> 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10 + (number - (number / 10) * 10);
            number = number / 10;

        }
        return reverse;
    }
```

//method that copies the value of the instance variable & swap the first and last digit of the number

```
        public string FirstLastDigit()
       {
           firstlast = number.ToString();
            while (firstlast.Length > 1)
            {
               {
                   char[] digits = firstlast.ToCharArray();
                   char firstDigit = digits[0];
                   digits[0] = digits[digits.Length - 1];
                   digits[digits.Length - 1] = firstDigit;
                   Console.WriteLine(new string(digits));
               }
           }
           return firstlast;
       }
```

//method that copies the value of the instance variable & swaps the second and third digit of the number

```
        public string SecondThirdDigit()
        {
            secondthird = number.ToString();
            while (firstlast.Length > 1)
            {
                    char[] digits = secondthird.ToCharArray();
                    char firstDigit = digits[1];
                    digits[1] = digits[digits.Length - 2];
                    digits[digits.Length - 2] = firstDigit;
                    Console.WriteLine(new string(digits));


            }
            return secondthird;
        }
```

//Main method that creates an object, assigns a four-digit number to the instance variable, and tests all methods

```
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           myClass myNum = new myClass();

           myNum.GetNumber();

           Console.WriteLine("ENTER THE NUMBER");
           myNum.number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine("\nNumber is " + myNum.number);
           Console.ReadLine();


           myNum.SumDigits();
           Console.WriteLine("\nSum is " + myNum.sum);

           myNum.RevNum();
           Console.WriteLine("\nThe reverse of number " + myNum.reverse);

           myNum.FirstLastDigit();
           Console.WriteLine("\nThe swap of first and last digit is" + myNum.firstlast);

           myNum.SecondThirdDigit();
           Console.WriteLine("\nExchange of Second and third digit is" + myNum.secondthird);

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? In every method you override your root number.. Create a copy of this number before change it

Comment: Which portion of code doesn't work? What is the error you get ?

Comment: the RevNum()  , SecondThirdDigit &  FirstLastDigit methods do not give the right output .. they r just giving 0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look for you and your code was 99% correct.  Nice work there.  I only had to make a few minor changes to get everything working.

For the `SumDigits()` and `RevNum()`, you were using `number` directly.  The problem with that is when you did `number = number / 10`, you were overwriting the number the user entered with a new one.  Eventually `number` became 0 after `Sum()` was done... so by the time the other 3 methods executed they were trying to do their actions on the number 0.

To fix this, I assigned `number` to a temp variable in these two methods.

For the `SecondThirdDigit()` and `FirstLastDigit()` methods, your formula was also correct.  However, you assigned `firstlast` to a 4-digit number and then had a while loop that executed while `firstlast.length > 1`.  Because the length was 4 and your loop never changed this, this became a never-ending loop.  I'm not sure why you thought you needed a loop here?

Anyway to fix this, I removed the loop and your code now works.  Also you were writing the result of this directly to the console instead of assigning it to your `firstlast` and `secondthird` variables, so I fixed those as well.

Other than that, everything else is unchanged from your code.  Here's an updated version for you that should work properly now:

```
//method to calculate and return the sum of the digits of the instance variable
public int SumDigits()
{
    // Assigned number to temp variable
    int tempNumber = number;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        r = tempNumber % 10;
        tempNumber = tempNumber / 10;
        sum = sum + r;
    }

    return sum;
}

//method that copies the value of the instance variable, and then returns the value of the copy in a reverse order
public int RevNum()
{
    // Assigned number to temp variable
    int tempNumber = number;

    while (tempNumber > 0)
    {
        reverse = reverse * 10 + (tempNumber - (tempNumber / 10) * 10);
        tempNumber = tempNumber / 10;
    }
    return reverse;
}

//method that copies the value of the instance variable & swap the first and last digit of the number
public string FirstLastDigit()
{
    firstlast = number.ToString();

    char[] digits = firstlast.ToCharArray();
    char firstDigit = digits[0];
    digits[0] = digits[digits.Length - 1];
    digits[digits.Length - 1] = firstDigit;
    // Assigned result to firstlast instead of console output
    firstlast = new string(digits);  

    return firstlast;
}

//method that copies the value of the instance variable & swaps the second and third digit of the number
public string SecondThirdDigit()
{
    secondthird = number.ToString();

    char[] digits = secondthird.ToCharArray();
    char firstDigit = digits[1];
    digits[1] = digits[digits.Length - 2];
    digits[digits.Length - 2] = firstDigit;
    // Assigned result to secondthird instead of console output
    secondthird = new string(digits);

    return secondthird;
}
```

Comment: Yay , its working now. Thank you so much for not only fixing my code but giving a detailed explanation as well. It really helped. Once again Thanks a lot.